# Unable to post data as Json using dojo.xhrPost() in asp,net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dojo

I am using dojo 1.8.3 with asp.net mvc. I am stuck with one problem. I'm trying to post data from one form as JSON (well I have a specific reason to post as json rather than JSON). So when I post I am getting a null string at the controller side. Below is my javascript code

```
   var xhrArgs = { url: rootPath + "Home/CreateNewPattern/",
            postData: dojo.toJson({ Name: "name1", TimeSpan: "10" }),
            handleAs: "text",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
            load: function (data) {
                console.log("Create pattern form posted");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                // We'll 404 in the demo, but that's okay.  We don't have a 'postIt' service on the
                // docs server.
                alert("Error during Form posting");
            }
        }

        // Call the asynchronous xhrGet
        var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

My action method inside controller is

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateNewPattern(string newPattern)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Name of the pattern is " + newPattern);

            return RedirectToAction("DisplayPatternManagement");
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're POSTing `Name` and `TimeSpan` properties, but your action accepts a single property named `newPattern`.

That obviously won't work.

Comment: Hi SLaks, Thanks for your instant reply. But can you tell me how will I process a complex object. Do I need to have as many string parameters as my object attributes.

Comment: @Sajan: No; you can make your action take a class with writable properties.

Comment: Will the serialization from JSON to .net happen automatically. I heard that it will happen in JQuery. Can any one give me one working example

Comment: @Sajan: I've never used Dojo.  Check their documentation.

Comment: @SLaks, "Check their documentation"?  Sorry but that answer is pretty poor.  Why answer a dojo question if you've never done dojo?

Comment: @Jessemon: I was answering the ASP.Net MVC part of the question.